# Spring boot - Getting error after updating base image for java

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, eclipse-temurin

I updated container base image from `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` to `eclipse-temurin:8-jdk` in Dockerfile. No other change is done. When I created pods using updated Docker file. I am getting below error:

```
]org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:  Application run failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'MyClassService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
```

From above error it is clear that application not able to find autowired properties. I have defined those properties in pods yaml file and it is working fine with openjdk image.

Why after updating to `eclipse-temurin:8-jdk` I am getting this error.